# Можно ли выводить в бота столько сообщений сколько записей от пользователя в БД?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite3, aiogram

Пользователь может добавлять сколько угодно записей в БД. После нажатия на инлайн кнопку пользователю должны приходить записи которые он сделал (каждая запись в отдельном сообщении). Возможно ли такое осуществить?

```py
elif a.data == 'my_baza':
    conn = sqlite3.connect('bigben.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    result = cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM baza WHERE user_id = "{a.message.chat.id}"').fetchall()
    result1 = cursor.execute(
        f'SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM baza WHERE user_id = "{a.message.chat.id}"').fetchone()
    await bot.send_message(a.message.chat.id, f'text')
```

Comment: @oleksandrio   С машиной состояний FSM я знаком, но как она поможет выводить каждый раз разное количество сообщений?

Answer (score 0):

```
elif a.data == 'my_baza':
    conn = sqlite3.connect('bigben.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    user_records = cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM baza WHERE user_id = "{a.message.chat.id}"').fetchall()
    for record in user_records:
        await bot.send_message(a.message.chat.id, record)
```